# How to read a JSON object in Controller and pass it to view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have a json object `name.json` as follows:

```
{ "name": "abc", "email": "xyz@gmail.com" }
```

I want to read this Json in a controller (`say_controller.rb`) and pass it to view:

```
class SayController < ApplicationController
  def hello  
    file = File.new("/assets/name.json", "r")
    while (line = file.gets)
      @json_obj = @json_obj + #{line}
    end
    file.close
  end
```

How do I pass this to the view file (hello.html.rb) and use it?

Comment: @json_obj will be available within your view.

Answer (score 0):

No need to pass explicitly to the view, @json_obj is already available in your view hello.html.erb

Comment: I need to pass it to a javascript. Can you share some demo code?

Comment: Where is your javascript code? Want to respond to ajax request?